# XSL - Rename element with value

Tags: xml, xslt

Just tryng to learn XSLT. Please refer Input and Output documents
Input xml is only a potion of the document. There are more record levels in this document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<record level="1">
   <GROUP>ABC</GROUP>
   <NAME>1100000000111</NAME>
</record>
```

Desired output
I would like to rename `<record level="1">` to `<record_level1>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<record_level1>
   <GROUP>ABC</GROUP>
   <NAME>1100000000111</NAME>
</record_level1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start with an [identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) to copy all content as the default behavior, then you can add a specialized template to match the `record` elements that have a `@level` attribute. Inside that template, create an element with the name concatenating the element name with the attribute name and value:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="record[@level]">
        <xsl:element name="{concat(name(), '_level', @level)}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the `{}` curly braces used inside of the element name attribute. It would otherwise expect a string literal. The [attribute value template](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xslt-30-20170608/#attribute-value-templates) allows you to execute code to construct that name value, using the [`concat()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-3/#func-concat) function.

Comment: Yeah, good point. It's not necessary.

Comment: Thanks Mads.
It seems to be working partially. It does not replace <record level="1"> but add a new tag <record_level1>. I just need to replace <record level="*"> with <record_level*> where * can be 1,2,3 etc.

e.g.

Output
<record_level1>
 <record level="1">
  <GROUP>ABC</GROUP>
  <NAME>2300000000111</NAME>
  <record level="2">
   <GROUP>XYZ</GROUP>
   <record level="3">
    <GROUP>PPP</GROUP>
   </record>
  </record>
 </record>
</record_level1>

Comment: Instead of `<xsl:copy-of select="."/>` you should use `<xsl:apply-templates/>`.

Comment: P.S. I would also take full advantage of attribute value template and write simply `<xsl:element name="{name()}_level{@level}">`.

Comment: Thanks Mads and Michael
It works like a charm now. :)